# How could I Substract two different cells of the same column

Tags: c#, telerik

[image: I have Procedure, That executed result is look like this:]

Where I want to subtract the Open Balance  Cells if there a same group Name ,I mean here  Balance_type 0 is debit and 1 is credit
  I am expecting result is debit-credit of Open Balance with the same Group Name

My REAL SQL statement is this one:

```
SELECT 
    tblLedgerGroup.group_type, tblLedgerGroup.group_name, tblLedgerGroup_1.group_name AS [Group Name]
    , SUM(tblLedgerNames.op_balance) AS [Open Balance]
    , tblLedgerNames.balance_type
    , SUM(tblCashLedger.debit) AS [Total Debit]
    , SUM(tblCashLedger.credit) AS [Total Credit]
FROM 
     tblLedgerGroup 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblLedgerGroup AS tblLedgerGroup_1 ON tblLedgerGroup.group_id = tblLedgerGroup_1.parent_group_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblLedgerNames ON tblLedgerGroup_1.group_id = tblLedgerNames.group_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblCashLedger ON tblLedgerNames.ledger_id = tblCashLedger.account_id 
GROUP BY 
    tblLedgerGroup.group_type, tblLedgerGroup.group_name, tblLedgerGroup_1.group_name, tblLedgerNames.balance_type
```